# Styled-Component will not return in React "code unreachable"

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Anyone have an idea why my styled-component is unreachable in my return

?

```
import React from "react";

import styled from "styled-components";

export const CoinHeaderGridStyled = styled.div`

 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr;

 `
export default function () {
return

<CoinHeaderGridStyled>
  
</CoinHeaderGridStyled>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in a sandbox. I made some fixes and it worked. I think it's all about how you placed that component.

```
import React from "react";

import styled from "styled-components";

export const CoinHeaderGridStyled = styled.div`
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr;

 `
export default function () {
return (<CoinHeaderGridStyled />)
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, just needed parenthesis, the weird thing is i haven't used them for multiple other return statements doing the exact same thing and i swear i even tried that a few times any way, classic

Comment: If it helped you, please consider accepting the answer, I would be grateful :)